# SoftLayer API: can a user access multiple accounts?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can a user access multiple accounts via the SoftLayer REST API?

If so, is the request below correct?  I thought I submitted this request this last week with an invalid accountID and received an empty response (as expected).  Today all my virtual guests are returned whether I enter a valid accountId or not.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/<accountId>/VirtualGuests
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the SoftLayer username and API information in the request. For example I use exports depending on if I am working on my Personal projects or work projects.

### Work

```
curl -s https://$SOFTLAYER_USERNAME:$SOFTLAYER_API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests
```

### Personal

```
curl -s https://$PERSONAL_USERNAME:$PERSONAL_API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests
```

The API will know the account you are getting information from based on the username and API key you specify.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IBMid linked in two accounts(I believe that you refer to this), you will have two usernames generated , one for each account with their api keys (if you are using the API). For example in my case:

> mail: test@softlayer.com
>
> **Account 1**
>
> - Account: 111222
> - username: 111222_test@softlayer.com
> - apiKey: Generated
>
> **Account 2**
>
> - Account: 111333
> - username: 111333_test@softlayer.com
> - apiKey: Generated

So, you need to use the proper credentials for the account from which you wish to retrieve the VSIs

Rest Request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests

Method: Get
```